# Access TFS 2010 Basic over internet

Tags: windows-7

**What I want:** Ability for contractors I have to access my TFS from the internet.

**What I have:**
Windows 7 machine running TFS 2010 Basic
Static IP Address from ISP
AirPort Extreme Router

**What I have done so far:**
I have setup port mapping on my router to forward public port 1723 to private port 8080 (which is where my tfs is).

If I try to access tfs using http://staticip:1723/tfs/web or through VS static ip and port, it prompts me for a username and password but no matter what I type i get error TF31003. It seems like I am almost there.

Am I missing something in my setup? Is there an easy/cheap way to open up TFS to the people I want to give access to? Everything I have seen online does not apply to Windows 7, only Windows Server.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you are logging in with a domain account as domain\username, and then make sure that account has been setup in TFS to access your files.

Comment: @AaronS I forgot to mention in the original post, but that is what I am doing. I have tried two different accounts, both of which work if I am local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So stupid me! Doing what i did does work. When I wrote the question, I was trying to access TFS as though I was not on my network, while still on my network.

Once I got to the office and tried it, it let me in.